# 'abstract class' versus 'normal class' for a reusable library

Tags: c#, .net, abstract-class, base-class

I'm developing a reusable library and have been creating abstract classes, so the client can then extend from these.

**QUESTION: Is there any reason in fact I should use an abstract class here as opposed to just a normal class?**

Note - Have already decided I do not want to use interfaces as I want to include actual default methods in my library so the client using it doesn't have to write the code.

EDIT:  So I'm fishing for any advantages I can't think of.  For example when upgrading the library would use of an abstract class lessen impact on client code - I can't see it would in this case no?

Comment: Since you cannot instantiate an abstract class, making classes abstract would *force* the client to extend them in order to use them.

Comment: Extending via inheritance is, in general, more difficult than using a library with composition and event handlers.  As for abstract classes vs. interfaces, you can get around the issue of 'default' methods using extension methods for the interfaces, which is sometimes cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you want to force the end users to inherit from your classes, there should be no reason to use *abstract*.

If you want to make your classes inheritable and easily extensible, use *virtual* on your methods and make sure you have usable *protected* constructors.

Comment: hard to choose - but this answer mentioned the virtual & public constructors advice which sounds good advice

Comment: I have to change public to protected (which is the more technically correct term)

Comment: The framework guidelines indicate that you should provide at least one concrete implementation of abstract classes or interfaces, sort of as a "proof of concept" that the class really makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

The motivation for the abstract class is to require clients to override the class. Your decision on whether the class should be abstract or not depends primarily on whether the abstract is missing some fundamental behavior that only an user of the class can supply.

You can usually tell you need your class to be abstract if you use a template method of some sort, where "plug in the hole in this behavior" completes the logic of he class. If your class is useful without some user-supplied logic, you probably don't need the class to be abstract.

As an example, frameworks usually can't make decisions on behalf of their users in terms of things like object state validation, printing, display, and so on, and they would need to defer to concrete implementations by the clients.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between an abstract class and a non-abstract one is that you can't instantiate the former and it MUST be overriden. It is really up to you to determine whether or not an instance of the base class makes sense on its own.

Let me show you two cases. One is where abstract class makes sense and one where it doesn't.

```
public abstract class Animal {
  public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class Dog : Animal {
  public Bark(){}
}

public class Cat : Animal {
  public Meaow(){}
}
```

In this scenario we have a common base `Animal` that provides implementation for `Name` property. It makes no sense to instantiate Animal by itself as there are no animals in the world that are just animals, they are wither dogs or cats or something else.

Here is a case where it makes sense to have a non-abstract base.

```
class Path {
  public Path(IList<Point> points) {
    this.Points = new ReadOnlyCollection<Point>(points);
  }
  public ReadOnlyCollection<Point> Points {get;}
}

class RectanglePath : Path{
  public SquarePath (Point origin, int height, int width) : 
   base(new List<Point>{origin, new Point(origin.X + width, point.Y}, ....){

  }
}
```

Here Path that is not subclassed makes sense, we can create any arbitrary shape, but it might be more convenient to use a sublass for more specific shapes.

Comment: I was wondering if an abstract class my give some benefits - e.g. when upgrading the library would this lessen impact on client code - I can't see it would in this case no?

Comment: Not really. It doesn't change the level of coupling - i.e. in both cases you need to inherit from the base class. The upgrade potential comes down to the library design, not whether or not the class is abstract.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are a little confused about the difference between a virtual method and an abstract class. You don't need to mark your class as abstract unless you determine that it doesn't make sense on it's own. This is useful in areas where you might have shared behaviors between multiple classes.

Sounds to me like you just need a regular class and some methods that are virtual.

Comment: I'm fishing for any advantages I can't think of. For example when upgrading the library would use of an abstract class lessen impact on client code - I can't see it would in this case no?

Comment: There are not many. Even if you don't mark it virtual the programmer consuming your library can construct a method with the "new" keyword to override your method. Marking your methods as virtual makes it so that the consumer doesn't need to use the "new" keyword to override it. In other words, it's more natural.

Comment: Use of the `new` keyword never results in overriding.  That's kind of the point.  It lets you steal the name for your own use but there is NO polymorphism, which is a fundamental part of overriding.

Comment: Yes, you are technically correct. However, semantically, what's the difference? In both cases you want to replace the existing functionality with your own. I should have said "replace" instead of "override" but the concept applies.